# Find the values of x where curve is concave

Tags: derivatives, curves

This is a question found in an A-Level math book.

> Given a curve
>
> $$f(x) = \frac{\cos2x}{e^x}, 0\le x\le\pi$$
>
> Determine the interval where $f(x)$ is concave.

According to the math book:

> The function $f(x)$ is concave on a given interval if and only if $f''(x) \le 0$ for every $x$ in that interval.

Also

> The point at whitch a curve changes from being concave to convex is called a **point of inflection**.
>
> A point of inflection is a point at which $f''(x)$ changes sign.

Hence, to calculate the interval, I first calculates the second derivative of $f(x)$:

$$f''(x)=\frac{4\sin2x-3\cos2x}{e^x}$$

From this point and onwards, I can either use the definition of concavity or the definition of the point of inflection to find the interval.

---

## Using the definition of concavity

Set $f''(x) \le 0$:

$$\therefore\frac{4\sin2x-3\cos2x}{e^x} \le 0 $$
$$\because e^x > 0$$
$$\therefore4\sin2x-3\cos2x \le 0$$
$$\therefore\tan2x \le 0.75$$
Hence, the answer is
\begin{align}
0\le &x \le-0.322\\
\pi/4\le &x \le1.892\\
0.75\pi\le &x\le\pi\\
\end{align}

---

## Using the definiton of point of inflection

The point of inflection is at $x=0.322$ and $x=1.892$.

And from the first derivative, one can find a local minimal at $x=1.34$ meaning the curve between the two point of inflection is convex.

Hence, the answer is
\begin{align}
0\le &x \le-0.322\\
1.892\le &x\le\pi\\
\end{align}

---

Which one is correct? And why is the other incorrect?

---

## Update

I think both approaches are valid, but a mistake is produced when I divide $sin$ by $cos$ in the first answer. Is it because $\cos2x < 0$ when $0.25\pi< x <0.75\pi$, so $\le$ needs to be changed to $\ge$? i.e.

\begin{cases}
\tan2x \le 0.75, &0\le x<0.25\pi \text{    and    } 0.75< x<\pi\\
\tan2x \ge 0.75, &0.25\pi <x<0.75\pi\\
\end{cases}

Solving this gives the second answer.

Comment: You could verify your answer by checking the graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hsbfkpurvk

Comment: @NoChance I kinda know the second answer is correct, but I couldn't prove why the first one is wrong.

Comment: One thing to check is when $tan(2x)<=0.75$.

Comment: In using the definition of the point of inflection, don't you mean $0.892\pi ≤ x ≤ \pi$? Your answer for that point doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @TobyMak good spotting but I meant 1.892 not $1.892\pi$ or $0.892\pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is 
\begin{align}
0\le &x \le0.322\\
1.892\le &x\le\pi\\
\end{align}

A proper way to solve the inequity,

$$4\sin2x-3\cos2x \le 0$$

is to follow the steps below,

$$5 \left( \sin2x\cdot \frac 45 - \cos2x\cdot \frac 35 \right) \le 0$$

$$ \sin2x \cos\theta - \cos2x \sin\theta \le 0$$

where $\theta = \arccos(4/5) = 0.6435$. Thus,

$$\sin(2x-0.6435)\le0$$

Then,

$$-\pi\le 2x-0.6425\le0, \>\>\> \pi\le 2x-0.6425 \le 2\pi$$

Thus, with the given range $0\le x\le \pi$, the solution is,

$$
0\le x \le0.322, \>\>\>
1.892\le x\le\pi
$$

which can also be verified from the attached plot.
[image]

Comment: Would you mind writing down the steps from $$4\sin2x-3\cos2x \le 0$$ to $$5\sin(2x-0.6435)\le0$$ I can get to $$4\sin2x-3\sin(2x+\pi/2) \le 0$$ But how to proceed further?

Comment: @Anthony - I added a few more steps in the answer.

Comment: thanks, very useful. To make it clearer, I believe the equation is $$\sqrt{3^2+4^2} \left( \sin2x\cdot \frac {4}{\sqrt{3^2+4^2}} - \cdot \cos2x\cdot \frac {3}{\sqrt{3^2+4^2}} \right) \le 0$$

Comment: I still don't understand though, why isn't it valid to divide the inequity $4\sin2x-3\cos2x \le 0$ by $4\cos2x$. Is it because $\cos2x$ can be $0$ and negative and the inequality sign must be flipped accordingly like I suggested in the question's update?

Comment: @Anthony - Correct. Division could be problematic in solving inequalities due to either signs or singularities, which should be avoided

Answer (score 0):

Solving $\tan 2x ≥ 0.75$;

$$2x ≥ \tan^{-1} 0.75, \tan^{-1} 0.75+\pi$$
$$x ≥ \frac{\tan^{-1} 0.75}{2}, \frac{\tan^{-1} 0.75+\pi}{2}$$

But you also need to take in account the asymptotes. Left of the asymptotes, the answer is positive, and right of the asymptotes, the answer is negative:

$$x < \frac{\pi}{4},  x < \frac{3 \pi}{4}$$

Can you continue?

Comment: No I can't lol...Head is burning, can't work it out. I have plotted the tan(x), cos(x) and sin(x) curves and I can definitely tell, from the curves, that $\tan x < 1$ is not the same as $\sin x < \cos x$. I just can't prove it with equations.